# Why we can't apply Cauchy-Lipschitz to $x^{3}y^{\prime} = y^2$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm self-studying differential equations. I've an exercise which is :

3. Consider the differential equation $x^3y^{\prime} = y^2$.
   a) Prove that the null function is an solution of the equation. Why we can't apply Cauchy-Lipschitz ?

I'm confident to do the analysis part by my own, if I knew the statement of Cauchy-Lipschitz, my only problem is that the polycopié I'm reading is neither clear nor complete.

Comment: The equation is separable though! :)

Comment: Indeed why can't you? $f(x,y)=y^2/x^3$ is perfectly differentiable wherever it is defined. The claim would need to also state either a domain for the ODE or an initial condition

Comment: @LutzLehmann $f(x, y) = y^2/x^3$ is locally Lipschitz compared to the second variable on $\mathbb{R}^{*} \times \mathbb{R}$, so we can apply Cauchy-Lipschitz, that also what I think.